AWS CDK v2: Restrict Cloudfront distribution access to specific folders in S3 with OAC
Now that the AWS CDK has L2 construct OAC support, I've attempted to use it on my project, however, since it now automatically creates the relevant S3 bucket policy rule for me, I'm struggling to modify it to restrict access to only certain directories.
Using the following code:
const bucket = new Bucket(this, 'MyBucket', {
  bucketName: 'my-bucket',
  blockPublicAccess: BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
  removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  autoDeleteObjects: true
});

const dist = new Distribution(this, 'Distribution', {
  defaultBehavior: {
    // Using new S3BucketOrigin construct with OAC functionality built in
    origin: S3BucketOrigin.withOriginAccessControl(bucket),
    viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS
  },
  domainNames: [domainName],
  certificate,
});

The following policy is automatically created on the bucket:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/the-autodelete-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject*",
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::123456789012:distribution/ABCDEFGHIJKLMN"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

How would I now go about modifying this policy via CDK to only allow access to certain directories?
Thank you

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/30675f01aa2a4c87dcdf493140c257119eb16af1/packages/aws-cdk-lib/aws-cloudfront-origins/lib/s3-bucket-origin.ts#L173 does not support what you want. If you want to really change the automatically created policy you can try and modify the statement that was added to the bucket policy, but this is quite fragile and might break in a few versions...

@luk2302 Thank you very much Lukas. Linking to the relevant code was extremely helpful.
Is there a way to achieve this using lvl1 constructs as I really don't want to be modifying the policy statement? I see the origins.s3Origin is now deprecated too.

Thank you to @luk2302 for directing me to the source to confirm it's not possible with S3BucketOrigin.withOriginAccessControl.
I then realised that Deny statements in S3 bucket policies always override Allow statements, so in my case, where I need to restrict access to certain "directories", I managed to add a Deny statement to the bucket policy afterwards:
bucket.addToResourcePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
  effect: iam.Effect.DENY,
  principals: [new iam.ServicePrincipal('cloudfront.amazonaws.com')],
  actions: ['s3:GetObject'],
  notResources: [
    `${bucket.bucketArn}/assets/*`,
    `${bucket.bucketArn}/tmp/*`
  ],
  conditions: {
    StringEquals: {
      'AWS:SourceArn': `arn:aws:cloudfront::${this.account}:distribution/${dist.distributionId}`
    }
  }
}));

I hope this helps someone.
Any feedback on better ways to achieve this would be appreciated.
